# Pandas - unable to calculate moving average

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to calculate SMA: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/moving-averages-in-pandas

I would like to get the SMA for all values but I'm only getting 5. I have 17 values in the frame that I want to get values for. If I increase the rolling window I am not getting any values at all for SMA, why is that?

Thanks for any help as I'm new to Pandas

```
    def example(self):
    frame = {'date': ['2017-06-19', '2017-06-16', '2017-06-15', '2017-06-14', '2017-06-13', '2017-06-12', '2017-06-09', '2017-06-08', '2017-06-07', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-05', '2017-06-02', '2017-06-01', '2017-05-31'], 'indexes': ['146.3400', '142.2700', '144.2900', '145.1600', '146.5900', '145.4200', '148.9800', '154.9900', '155.3700', '154.4500', '153.9300', '155.4500', '153.1800', '152.7600']}

    df = pd.DataFrame(frame)
    df['SMA'] = df.iloc[:, 1].rolling(window=4).mean()
    print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
         date   indexes     SMA
0  2017-06-19  146.3400       NaN
1  2017-06-17  142.2700       NaN
2  2017-06-16  144.2900       NaN
3  2017-06-15  145.1600  144.5150
4  2017-06-14  146.5900  144.5775
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating a moving average, you need `n` samples for it, which is the size of your moving window. Since you've set `window=4`, then you need 4 samples for your average to be computed. That being said, these `NaN` values just show that, in that point, there is not enough data to compute MA with window size = 4.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible to get the moving avg for today unless using window=1? And if I use 1 then it's pretty useless? How do I increase the number of rows?

Comment: A moving average relies on a moving window of samples. For it to work correctly, you really need the number of samples specified to the moving window. You could write some kind of script to generate values for these `NaN` data using fewer samples, but then they wouldn't be exactly a moving average. And yeah, a moving window size of 1 is pretty useless, because it refers to a copy of the latest value. To increase the number of rows you probably need more data. I don't know what data is this you're showing nor from where it's coming from, then I can't help you get more data.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

If you must calculate your rolling mean always with a window of 4, then you need to drop the results with `'NA'`. However, if what you want is just to calculate a rolling mean when you don't have enough observations, you could use something like `df[column_name].rolling(window=4, min_periods=1)`. But note that this not not proper rolling mean. Here's an example.

### Example

```py
# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Date'])
df['Counts'] = [16,  6,  8,  5, 15,  7]

# Calculate rolling mean with min_preriods=1
df['rolling_mean'] = df.Counts.rolling(window=4, min_periods=1).mean()
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```sh
        Date  Counts  rolling_mean
0 2020-01-01      16         16.00
1 2020-01-02       6         11.00
2 2020-01-03       8         10.00
3 2020-01-04       5          8.75
4 2020-01-05      15          8.50
5 2020-01-06       7          8.75
```

### Dropping `NA` values

```py
df.Counts.rolling(window=4).mean().dropna()

## Output
# 3    8.75
# 4    8.50
# 5    8.75
# Name: Counts, dtype: float64
```

### Replacing `NA` values with some preferred value

Say, you want to replace all `NA` values with a `0`. Here's what you need to do.

```py
df.Counts.rolling(window=4).mean().fillna(0)

## Output
# 0    0.00
# 1    0.00
# 2    0.00
# 3    8.75
# 4    8.50
# 5    8.75
# Name: Counts, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @brodude Please take a look at this option.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your very good explanation. I would have set it as solution but Gabriel's set me in the right direction and I had already set his answer as solution. Thanks again for your long and good walktrough

Comment: @brodude No problem. But if see merit in any answer, please consider voting them up. Also, please note that Stackoverflow supports upvoting of the best answer at any point of time. As the author of the question, you are the judge of which answer is most informative and helpful. If you think a certain answer is better, there is no hard-and-fast rule that you can not change your previously chosen (*accepted*) answer. We should choose answers solely based on their merit and value addition: and I see accepted answers getting *unaccepted* on SO often when a better answer is available. Thank you.